# Calling other js file function into AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have `1.js` file which has the function `_HideErrorBox()`, and I would like you to use it in `2.js` file but in AJAX call,

I am loading `1.js` and `2.js` in sequence,

Here is `1.js`

```
var Calculations = function() {

    var _HideErrorBox = function() {
        $(document).on("click", ".close", function() {
            $("#errorbox").hide();
        });
    };

    return {
        init: function() {
            _HideErrorBox();
        }
    };
}();

jQuery(function() {
    Calculations.init();
});
```

And this is `2.js`

```
var _CreateBill = function() {

    $(".addButton").on("click", function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/to/url/create",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {

                _HideErrorBox();

            }
        });
    });
};
```

The problem is when, AJAX call is finished, it shows that `Uncaught ReferenceError: _HideErrorBox is not defined`

Is it possible to call a function from another JS in AJAX call?

Comment: If your vague description of the code is correct, then you won't have the problem you describe. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Without seeing exactly how `_HideErrorBox` is defined in `1.js`, we cannot answer this question but `1.js` is certainly where your problem will be

Comment: @Phil, added code for HideBox

Comment: I see no reason for you to need to call `_HideErrorBox()` in your AJAX success handler since all it does is set up a `document` level event handler which will have already been done in `1.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [revealing module pattern](https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/bb0eec99c02dda6aac0e041d0d4d7bf2) to **prevent** every function you create from being a global.

`_HideErrorBox` is explicitly designed to be a private variable so you **can't** do what you want to do.

You should rethink the structure of your code. e.g. should 2.js be part of the `Calculations` module?

---

That said calling `_HideErrorBox` **again** is pointless. It's **already** bound a delegated event handler to the `document`.